# How to do an INSERT so only valid rows of data are inserted and invalid ones are ignored?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, I have one table "StagingTable1" that has 2 fields, ID and Name where Name can be null and it as three rows of data

```
ID  Name
1   Joe
2   Moe
3   BAD_DATA_OR_NULL_VALUE
```

I also have "ProdTable2" that has 2 fields ID and Name but neither can have NULL values.

So, if I run `Insert into ProdTable2 (ID, Name) Select ID, Name from StagingTable1` it will throw an error because row 3 has a null value (or other bad data) for the Name. Is there a way to structure the Insert so that the 2 rows with valid names will insert into ProdTable2 but the third row will be ignored?

Comment: You might just need to use another tool like BCP or SSIS.

Comment: @JohnH . . . How do *you* define bad data?  That is certainly not a concept built into SQL Server.

Comment: The short answer is no. The slightly longer answer is - you must insert using RBAR. SSIS has this sort of functionality allowing you to redirect rows that generate errors for logging. TSQL does not. And I think your logic might be short-sighted. You (or someone else) will **really** want to know which row generated the error, the contents of that row, and the complete error message.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `WHERE` clause to filter out the bad rows. For example:

```
insert into prodtable2 (id, name) 
select id, name from stagingtable1 where name is not null
```

Comment: That won't work because there may be other reasons why the insert will fail. I'm looking for a generic defense against NULLS, wrong format, size of data, etc.

Comment: Well, you can write your own function and make as much analysis as you wish in there. But you still need to use it in WHERE clause.

Comment: @JohnH. Another option would be to add a [check constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017) but like The Impaler stated, it could also be done with a where clause, or using a trigger to do input validation. Triggers can be slow though :). wrong *size* is also handled by the column constraint by default. Format is where you would use a constraint.